# How to compare a file across repos in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

We have been using Visual Studio (now on 2022) with TFS for many years but are considering moving to Git for new solutions (we use an on-prem Azure DevOps server, if relevant). I have recently been playing around with a dummy solution, committing and pushing changes, but one area that I'm struggling with is doing a file compare.

If a file in my solution has an *uncommitted* change then I can compare it to what seems to be the local repo version, by R.clicking the file in solution explorer -> Git -> "Compare with unmodified".

How can I compare that file with the version in the *remote* repo?

And how can I compare versions of a file between local repo and remote repo?

Along a similar vein, I've found that I can view a file's history by right-clicking it in VS solution explorer -> View history. I assume this is showing me the file's history in the *local* repo, but how can I view a file's history in the *remote* repo?

I've found that from the VS "Git Repository" window, I can view the history of the *entire* remote repo by right-clicking "remotes/origin" -> "master". Similarly, I can compare the entire remote repo against the local repo via a "Compare origin/master with master" option in the same menu. I just can't find a way to perform these operations on an individual file.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do what you want.

Comment: It may help to think of a "repo" as a collection of commits, and some commits have branches pointing at them. (That's all branches are.) In VS, when you compare a *file* with it's unmodified version, or view the history of any *file*, you are doing so based on your *currently checked out commit*. If you change your currently checked out commit (e.g. to `origin/master`) you can change the results. Note, constantly checking out a different commit just to look at stuff isn't always efficient, so sometimes command line and/or other tools are helpful for this. (BTW, this might be the answer...)